# How to curve fit, Z variable dependent on X and Y?

Tags: python, linear-regression, visualization, overfitting

I'm trying to find the function for this visualization:
[image: Visualization]
I would like to get feedback if I'm taking the right approach. My approach:

1. These data points are created by a person. They are two independent variables (x and y axes) and one dependent variable (the colored dots).
2. I asked ChatGPT what I should do and it told me to try to fit the curve. Try different models and evaluate.
3. I randomly splitted the training and test data sets (80/20).
4. The models I tried: Decision tree, random forest, curve fit, linear regression, logistic regression and polynomial features.
5. All models gave bad results (negative r squared value) except for linear regression with PolynomialFeatures (r squared value of 0.339). But this results still seem low right?

Here is my data and code:

```
z,x,y
0.6,0,1
0.55,0.1,1
0.5,0.2,1
0.4,0.3,1
0.3,0.4,1
0.2,0.5,1
0.9,0,3
0.75,0.5,3
0.35,1,3
0.15,1.5,3
0.05,2,3
1,0,7
0.9,1,7
0.75,2,7
0.35,3,7
0.2,4,7
0.1,5,7
0.02,6,7
1,2,14
0.8,4,14
0.5,6,14
0.05,9,14
0.01,10,14
1,5,25
0.65,9,25
0.1,13,25
0.01,17,25
1,8,50
0.8,13,50
0.3,18,50
0.1,23,50
0.01,30,50
```

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("scores.csv")
X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
y = df.iloc[:, 0].values

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_poly = poly.transform(X_test)

poly_reg = LinearRegression()

poly_reg.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)

y_pred = poly_reg.predict(X_test_poly)

y_pred = np.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)
```

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong. I think this problem could be solved easier because when you look at the visual you can see a clear pattern. I'm looking for some confirmation to see if I'm taking the right approach. Any feedback?

Comment: Please add the code as actual text to the post instead of posting as an image. Additionally, it would help if you could also add (a link to) the data to the post so we don't have to manually copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your approach makes sense.

There are a couple of ways of reframing it:

- Change the evaluation metric from R² to one that is prediction oriented (e.g., MSE or MAE). R² is useful but has limitations.
- Given the figure shows evidence of a more complex relationship, it might be more useful to fit a more expressive model (e.g., kernel regression or isotonic regression).

Comment: The usual calculation of $R^2$ is a monotonic function of MSE, so I’m not sure how MSE is more useful. Could you please elaborate?